# PayPal-Ruby-SDK model name conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a Plan model in my app. And sometimes I'm catching the following error. After restarting the server it goes away for a while.

gem version(1.6.0)

How can it be fixed?

`NoMethodError in Subscriptions#index`

```
undefined method `map' for #<PayPal::SDK::REST::DataTypes::PlanList:0x007fbc494c13c0>
Did you mean?  tap
```

--

```
  Rendering subscriptions/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered subscriptions/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2145ms (ActiveRecord: 8.3ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `map' for #<PayPal::SDK::REST::DataTypes::PlanList:0x007fbc494c13c0>
Did you mean?  tap):
     7:       <div class="field">
     8:         <p class="control has-icons-left is-expanded">
     9:           <%= form.input_field :plan_id,
    10:            collection: @plans.map {|plan| ["#{plan.name} - $#{plan.cost}", plan.id]},
    11:            wrapper_html: { class: ' select is-fullwidth' }, class: 'input', label: false, prompt: 'Select a plan' %>
    12:           <span class="icon is-small is-left">
    13:             <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>

app/views/subscriptions/index.html.erb:10:in `block in _app_views_subscriptions_index_html_erb___836818763133109538_70223330120860'
app/views/subscriptions/index.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_subscriptions_index_html_erb___836818763133109538_70223330120860'
```

subscriptions controller index action

`def index
    @plans = Plan.all
  end`

**web console**

[image]

Comment: Could you give us the implementation of your Plan object ?

Comment: @romainsalles it just has 2 lines `has_many :subscriptions` and
`has_many :users, through: :subscriptions`. It's not about including enumerable since it works fine after restarting server.

Comment: I don't known the PayPal Gem. But looking at the documentation, I think you should try to call `Plan.all.members` or `Plan.all.to_hash` and look what you get in there. Because the `Plan.all` doesn't return an array but a `PlanList` object (@see: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/blob/master/lib/paypal-sdk/rest/data_types.rb#L2055)

Comment: @romainsalles I noticed that if I make a typo and save it then reload my browser with an error, then fix the typo and reload the browser again I get this error. So it might probably be a problem with spring preloader. `Plan.all.to_hash` returns an empty hash

Comment: Maybe you should just think of it like: `plans_list = Plan.all; plans_list.plans` (@see the specs: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/blob/master/spec/subscription_examples_spec.rb#L100)

Comment: The `Plan.all.each` method seems to be working as well: **controller =** https://github.com/samuelsimoes/rails-paypal-subscriptions-sample/blob/master/app/controllers/plans_controller.rb, **view =** https://github.com/samuelsimoes/rails-paypal-subscriptions-sample/blob/master/app/views/plans/index.html.erb

Comment: Did you tried to force ruby to find your class from the top level scope? `::Plan` should work.

Comment: @FedeBonisconti, like `::Plan.all`. That didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using namespaces instead of including a module solves the problem.

`PayPal::SDK::REST::Payment`